# ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception: com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Packet corrupt

Tags: java, linux, oracle

При вызове java source в oracle возвращается ошибка:

> ORA-29532: Java call terminated by uncaught Java exception:
>   com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Packet corrupt.

Идет попытка подключения к linux серверу (это сторонний сервер, не сервер БД) из базы данных. При первых запусках не закрывалась сессия JSCH (в коде не было `channel.disconnect`, `session.disconnect`).

Где и как можно посмотреть, какая открытая сессия мне мешает?

Comment: Смотрел в базе данных, на сервере приложения - ничего не увидел. Возможно, сессии сохраняются на сервере базы данных? Самое интересное, что из IDE все отрабатывает успешно. Проблема именно с вызовом из базы данных.

Comment: Что такое - "вызов java source"? Какую сессию вы ищете? Вы можете добавить релевантный код?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5013.htm#SQLRF01211
Java-код, который я вызываю процедурой-оберткой вида
create or replace procedure test(p_created in date, p_command in varchar2) as LANGUAGE java name 'com.callCMD (java.sql.Date, java.lang.String)';

Ищу сессию, которая мне не дает подключиться (согласно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27838523/jschexception-packet-corrupt).
Ребутнул ПК, сервер приложений, сервер БД, ошибка сохраняется.